# Displaying message after inserting data into SQL not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to display a success message after I have inserted data into my database, but it's not showing.

This is my code:

```
 protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ProjectName = txtProjectName.Text;
    string ProjectCode = txtProjectCode.Text;
    string ProjectDetails = txtProjectDetails.Text;

    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PROJECTS"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_projects (projectName, projectCode, projectDetails) VALUES (@ProjectName, @ProjectCode, @ProjectDetails)");

        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", txtProjectName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectCode", txtProjectCode.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDetails", txtProjectDetails.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Success", Toastr.Type.Success);
    }

}
```

If have also tried:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Success", Toastr.Type.Success);
    }
```

Not sure why this is not working?

Comment: hehe, in `catch` there will be no `"Success"`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! According to code above, if the code doesn't throw an exception you are not attempting to show anything. Add `Toastr.ShowToast("Data has been inserted!", "Success", Toastr.Type.Success);` at end of `con.Close;`...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  Thanks, its working great now.

Comment: @KeithKing welcome and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to issue a success message when you have an exception.

An Exception is basically an error which has been cause by your code.  So instead you should put your success message after your insert, and if no exception is thrown then it has worked.

```
SqlConnection con = null;   //Put this outside your try block
try
{
    con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PROJECTS"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_projects (projectName, projectCode, projectDetails) VALUES (@ProjectName, @ProjectCode, @ProjectDetails)");

    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", txtProjectName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectCode", txtProjectCode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectDetails", txtProjectDetails.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Success", Toastr.Type.Success);

}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error:  Oh no, it didn't work!", Toastr.Type.Failed);
}
finally
{
    //Close you connection (if set) in finally.  
    //This way it will also be closed if you do have an exception
    if(con != null)
        con.Close();
}
```

Also, in your current code the connection to the database will only be closed if your command is successful.  Which means if you have an exception then the connection stays open and you have a memory leak and resource problem.

So I moved this into a finally block, which will also be executed, regardless of exception or not.  But then you need to check that it is populated before trying to close

Comment: TBH if you are looking at moving the `con` field, how about removing that all together and just wrap the connection/command up in a `using` statement so the connection and command both get disposed?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ  Yes you are right but.  1)  But how far should we go to refactor code from the origin but keep it so that it is still understandable for somebody who is new?  2)  This also nicely introduces the purpose of finally to the try/catch block for the OP.

Comment: If you wanted to further validate the correct number of rows were affected the executenonquery method returns an int so if you're inserting just the one row you can validate this returns before showing the message.

Comment: You *might* want to add a condition - grab the return value from the `.ExecuteNonQuery` which indicates how many rows were affected by your statement. If it's **0** - then noting was inserted, so that might also be an "error" (or at least "warning") situation. Only if the return value is greater than 0, the operation succeeded  and inserted any data.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith  Thanks for the explanation and example.  Much appreciated!!

Comment: The only problem I have now is when I refresh the page it automatically adds the data again to the database.

Comment: @KeithKing  that is another problem, so if after trying, if you still can't resolve it then you should open another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

````cs
Try {
// All statements here are executed until exception is reached, if all statements pass then one can display a success message. Thus at the end of the try statement(s) add the success message there.
} 
Catch (Exception ex) {
// When Something goes wrong with the statements in Try then the exception message will be thrown.  
}
// I would rather suggest that a success message be thrown at the end of your try statement...```
````